# Oracle SQL to get rows from master even if there is none matching in detail

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Oracle SQL to get rows from master even if there is none matching in detail. Need row from the master only  for the parameter that has been passed. Parameter passed will be account number..

```
 SELECT m.face,
  m.device_num,
  reading_time,
  reading
FROM detail d,
  master FCICMTR
WHERE d.device_id    = m.device_id
AND m.account_number = 100050300;
```

Master

```
device_Num  Face Account    device_id
80149309    1    100050300  5554444
80149674    2    100050300  5554444
80000000    3    100050300  5554444
89348000    1    123131312  333333
97654322    1    424245445  444444
87654321    1    342441222  555555
87654321    2    178798978  555555
```

Detail

```
FACE DEVICE_ID  READING_TIME READING
1    5554444    28-FEB-17    4201
2    5554444    28-FEB-17    220465
1    5554444    27-FEB-17    4200
2    5554444    27-FEB-17    220443
1    5554444    26-FEB-17    4200
2    5554444    26-FEB-17    220377
1    333333     28-FEB-17    343434
1    555555     27-FEB-17    3434
2    555555     26-FEB-17    555
```

Need result like:

```
FACE DEVICE_NUM READING_TIME  READING
1    80149309   28-FEB-17     4201
2    80149674   28-FEB-17     220465
1    80149309   27-FEB-17     4200
2    80149674   27-FEB-17     220443
1    80149309   26-FEB-17     4200
2    80149674   26-FEB-17     220377
3    80000000   NULL          NULL
```

Please note that ... there is a row that I need in the result set i.e device_num = 80000000 which does not exist in detail table. This device num belongs to the same account number 100050300 is the reason why I need it.

Comment: You need to use an outer join then

Comment: You need an outer join, but that does not appear to be all.  The detail table contains `device_id` but not `face`, so it's unclear how you are matching different details to master rows with the same `device_id` but different `face`.

Comment: Thanks  xQbert. Tried that. But it gives me the device_id's in details table which I do not need.

Comment: Sorry friends, made a mistake while asking.  I have edited the table.

Comment: So outer join on `device_num` instead of `device_ID` and `face`..

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join.  Outer joins are used when you want all records from one table and only records from another table that match.

More on joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

In this case you want all master records meeting your criteria and records from detail if they match.

```
SELECT m.face,
  m.device_id,
  reading_time,
  reading
FROM detail d
RIGHT JOIN master FCICMTR
 on d.device_num    = m.device_Num
and d.face = m.face
WHERE m.account_number = 100050300;
```

---

This is what you have:

```
SELECT m.face,
  m.device_num,
  reading_time,
  reading
FROM detail d,
  master FCICMTR
WHERE d.device_id    = m.device_id  --this line causes the problem
AND m.account_number = 100050300;
```

Since no record exists in detail for device 80000000; it gets eliminated from your results. Thus you need the outer join.  Which can be expressed in older style notation as

```
WHERE d.device_num (+)= m.device_Num
  and d.face (+)=m.face
```

though antiquated or in the current standard notation using a left or right join as above.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `left join`:

```
SELECT m.face, m.device_id,
       d.reading_time, d.reading
FROM master m LEFT JOIN
     detail d
     ON d.device_id = m.device_id 
WHERE m.account_number = 100050300;
```

Notes:

- Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- `LEFT JOIN` is easy to understand.  It keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` evaluates to true, false, or NULL.  Non-matching rows have a `NULL` value.  You want to keep all rows in `master` (subject to the `where` condition), so it goes first.
- I fixed the table aliases in your query.